# epsilon Delta approach in Proving $\lim_{x \to 8} \sqrt[3]x=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

using epsilon Delta approach  Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 8} \sqrt[3]x=2$$

Given $\epsilon \gt 0$ we need to find $\delta=f(\epsilon)$ such that $$|x-a| \lt \delta$$ $\implies$

$$|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$$  So

$$|\sqrt[3]x -2| \lt \epsilon$$  $\implies$

$$2-\epsilon \lt \sqrt[3]x \lt 2+\epsilon$$  Or

$$(2-\epsilon)^3 \lt x \lt (2+\epsilon)^3$$  Now using

$(a-b)^3$ and neglecting higher powers of $\epsilon$ we get

$$8-12 \epsilon \lt x \lt 8+12\epsilon$$

So

$$-12 \epsilon \lt x-8 \lt 12 \epsilon$$

So $$\delta=12 \epsilon$$

But my book answer is $$\delta =min \left\{8-(2-\epsilon)^3, 8-(2+\epsilon)^3\right\}$$

can any one clarify this

Comment: You can't just "neglect" higher powers of $\epsilon$

Comment: why $\epsilon$ is a small positive number right?

Comment: And also the implications you have there are in the wrong direction from what you want

Comment: Still you can't neglect things like that.

Comment: yes i actually i have that doubt that why all the proofs of epsilon delta method follow backward approach?

Answer (score 3):

You have shown

$$|\sqrt[3] x-2|<\epsilon \iff (2-\epsilon)^3<x<(2+\epsilon)^3$$

This is equivalent to$$8-(2+\epsilon)^3<8-x<8-(2-\epsilon)^3$$

which is implied by

$$|x-8|<\delta = \min\{(2+\epsilon)^3-8,8-(2-\epsilon)^3\}$$

Comment: What's odd is that $8-(2+\epsilon)^3 < 0$ for $\epsilon >0$

Comment: It should rather be $(2+\epsilon)^3- 8$

Comment: @Max that's correct. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all note that such questions don't have a unique answer and hence trying to match the answer from the book does not make any sense. Second and *most importantly such questions are* **not** *an exercise to solve inequalities via algebraic manipulation*.

For any given $\epsilon>0 $ you need to ensure that the inequality $$|\sqrt[3]{x}-2|<\epsilon\tag{1}$$ holds by constraining the values of $x$ in a certain manner. The constraint on the values of $x$ needs to be of the form $0<|x-8|<\delta$ where the $\delta$ has to be chosen so that the inequality $(1)$ is ensured.

The correct strategy here is **not to solve the inequation $(1)$ to find all values of $x$ for which the inequality $(1)$ holds**, but rather to *find a simple expression in $x$, say $g(x) $, such that inequality $$|\sqrt[3]{x}-2|\leq g(x) \tag{2}$$ holds and then ensure that inequality $$g(x) <\epsilon\tag{3}$$ holds*. Ensuring that inequalities $(2)$ and $(3)$ hold automatically ensures that inequality $(1)$ holds and naturally ensuring these two inequalities will require some constraints on values of $x$ and we will combine these constraints into a single one to get something of the form $0<|x-8|<\delta$.

The crux of the problem is thus to find a suitable and simple expression $g(x) $ which satisfies $(2)$. And we would want it to be as simple as possible. Note that $$|\sqrt[3]{x}-2|=\left|\frac{x-8}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}+2\sqrt[3]{x}+4}\right|$$ Now we can observe that if $x>1$ then the denominator $$\sqrt[3]{x^{2}}+2\sqrt[3]{x}+4>1+2+4=7$$ and hence we have $$|\sqrt[3]{x}-2|<\frac{|x-8|}{7}$$ if $x>1$. We have thus found our $g(x) $ as $g(x) = |x-8|/7$. And we also have a constraint on $x$ namely $x>1$ so that this $g(x) $ works as expected. We can put this constraint as $0<|x-8|<7$. And then we need to ensure $g(x) =|x-8|/7<\epsilon$ which holds if we have the constraint on $x$ in the form of $0<|x-8|<7\epsilon$. We now combine the two constrains on $x$ as $$0<|x-8|<\min(7,7\epsilon)$$ and it is clear that we can take $\delta=\min(7,7\epsilon)$.

---

You can see that the above does not involve any messy algebra and gives a simple and clear answer (much simpler than the complicated answer given in your book).